# using INFORMATION_SCHEMA as root, error saying it doesnt exist?

Tags: php, mysql, information-schema

I'm using this php code to pull out the column headers in a test table I had created. However whenever I try to run the code it gives me this error: `There was an error running the query [Table 'meta_test.information_schema' doesn't exist]` from the information I've seen online it looks like my code should work, however this is the first time I've attempted something like this. Here is my code:

```
    $camp = $_POST['campaign'];
    $query = "SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$camp'";

    try{
        if(!$result = $db->query($query)){
            die('There was an error running the query [' . $db->error . ']');
        }

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result);
        echo "</pre>";
    }catch(exception $e){
        echo $e;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the table name:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = '$camp'
```

Comment: Ah I see what you're saying, sorry. Let me try that.
*edit* that works, thanks!